# Shell scripting and test expressions

Tags: shell

I'm trying to test whether a directory path exists when a file is passed to my script. I use dirname to strip and save the path. I want my script to run only if the path exists. This is my attempt below.

FILE=$1
   DIRNAME=`dirname $FILE`

if [ -z $DIRNAME ] ; then
       echo "Error no file path"
       exit 1
   fi

But this doesn't work. Actual when there is no file path `dirname $FILE` still returns "." to DIRNAME, i.e. this directory. So how do i distinguish between "." and "/bla/bla/bla".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
 
if [ -a $1] ; then echo "found file"; fi
```

?

Comment: This is true whether a file path exists or not. How can I test if DIRNAME is populated or holds "."

Comment: It was as simple as
   
    if [ $DIRNAME == "." ] ; then

I don't know why this did not work earlier. Must've made a mistake else-where.

Thanks very much for you quick response.

Comment: Paul, I'm glad you figured it out - and sorry that my response wasn't what you were looking for.  Typos preventing the code you posted from working can be easy to make and tough to spot :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure dirname is checking the filesystem for existence? What OS are you on? Most dirnames just do string manipulation, I believe. So this:

```
dirname /one/two/three
```

Returns /one/two even if /one doesn't exist.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
FILE=$1
DIRNAME=`dirname "$FILE"`
if [ ! -d "$DIRNAME" ]; then
    echo "$DIRNAME doesn't exist" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. I check this later. I'm got into something that need finished soon.